# Is it possible to use non-deterministic ECDSA signatures schemes for signing Ethereum transactions/messages?

Tags: signature

Is it possible to use a non-deterministic/probabilistic (choosing k randomly and not HMAC-derived from msgHash + privKey like [RFC 6979](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6979#section-3.2) states) ECDSA signature scheme for Ethereum Signatures? If yes, are there libraries implementing such scheme? It was hard for me to find any information about this topic. It feels like all libraries are using deterministic ECDSA.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, AWS sample shows it, but it does not include source code for ECDSA:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part2-use-aws-kms-to-securely-manage-ethereum-accounts/

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/indutny/elliptic or https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-secp256k1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible :)

Here's an example using [python-ecdsa](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/tree/master):

```py
from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256k1

def encode_func(r, s, _):
    return f"0x{r:032x}", f"0x{s:032x}"

# import the private key
sk = SigningKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(f"{0x1337:064x}"), curve=SECP256k1)
h = bytes.fromhex("72a2f9e2793e59981dda4cf1d2cf376338f6b8276fdd87265bb67d6fe9c28279")
sk.sign_digest(h, sigencode=encode_func)
# ('0x63243daa85a924272df05336d1f8c48881aadc8812bbf778b9da6eaebab2eddf', '0x80bd3d3c4bb4919519215e95416727e0c978ddaa2fc6bbb13784147fd0511aff')
```

Then, set a proper `v` value to pass the `ecrecover` verification:

```js
address addr = 0x71556C38F44e17EC21F355Bd18416155000BF5a6;
bytes32 h = 0x72a2f9e2793e59981dda4cf1d2cf376338f6b8276fdd87265bb67d6fe9c28279;
uint8 v = 27;
bytes32 r = 0x63243daa85a924272df05336d1f8c48881aadc8812bbf778b9da6eaebab2eddf;
bytes32 s = 0x80bd3d3c4bb4919519215e95416727e0c978ddaa2fc6bbb13784147fd0511aff;
require(addr == ecrecover(h, v, r, s));
```